# What is an efficient way to record google search using LoadRunner?

Tags: loadrunner

I tried to record "google search" Using LoadRunner and when i replay the script it is getting failed. Please provide me efficient way to record google search using loadrunner

Comment: What did you try. What errors did you get?

Answer (score -1):

You don't.  Read the license agreement.  You don't own, manage or control Google, nor likely do you have permission to test their site.  Also, the only supported interfaces for automation with Google are the ones provided by Google.

Just because you own a tactical nuclear device doesn't give you permission to point it at your neighbors and pull the trigger.

I recommend downloading and installing SugarCRM if you are just looking for a site to kick around.